# How to read/write a file in UTF-8 in Java?

Tags: java, utf-8, inputstream, outputstream

I am getting this error:

> io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence

The solution is to read and write a file in UTF-8.

My code is:

```
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
OutputStreamWriter bufferedWriter = new OutputStreamWriter( output, "UTF8");
input = new URL(url).openStream();
output = new FileOutputStream("DirectionResponse.xml");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
   output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("DirectionResponse.xml" ));
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("ppre_DirectionResponse.xml");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

I'm reading a url and writing it to a file *DirectionResponse.xml*. Then reading *DirectionResponse.xml* and writing the same as *ppre_DirecionResponse.xml* for processing.

**How do I change this so that reading and writing is done in UTF-8?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First, you need to call `output.close()` (or at least call `output.flush()`) before you reopen the file for input. That's probably the main cause of your problems.

Then, you shouldn't use `FileReader` or `FileWriter` for this because it always uses the platform-default encoding (which is often not UTF-8). From [the docs for `FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html):

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate.

You have the same problem when using a `FileWriter`. Replace this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("DirectionResponse.xml" ));
```

with something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream("DirectionResponse.xml"), "UTF-8"));
```

and similarly for `fstream`.

Comment: @Aubin - Sure, at least if you're talking about the input stream: `URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();`. Then use `is` as the input stream.

Comment: @user905911 - I noted another problem with your code. See the first paragraph of my revised answer.

Comment: @TedHopp : Sir, it worked. But i dont no how to change FileWriter. Should i change to OutputStreamWriter ?

Comment: ok so i changed that to 
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("ppre_DirectionResponse.xml");
      Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");

Comment: Since Java 7 it could be done in a shorter way: `BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("DirectionResponse.xml"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Answer (score 2):

[Read and Write UTF-8 File in Java](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-read-and-write-utf8-file-in-java/164)

I see you are writing in utf-8 but not specifically reading in utf-8. Follow the example I've provided in the link.

```
try {
   Reader reader =
      new InputStreamReader(
         new FileInputStream(args[0]),"UTF-8");
   BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(reader);
   Writer writer =
      new OutputStreamWriter(
         new FileOutputStream(args[1]), "UTF-8");
   BufferedWriter fout = new BufferedWriter(writer);
   String s;
   while ((s=fin.readLine())!=null) {
      fout.write(s);
      fout.newLine();
   }

            //Remember to call close. 
            //calling close on a BufferedReader/BufferedWriter 
            // will automatically call close on its underlying stream 
   fin.close();
   fout.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i read that but the problem is tht i need to read a URL, those functions dont read url.

Comment: @user905911 u dindn't specify that in your question

Comment: `fin.close();` and `fout.close();` must b called in a `finally` block. And since Java 7 it's better to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) approach.